# Building a simple news feed in node + Mongodb + Redis

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, redis, node-redis

My goal is to build a simple news feed in node.js with the help of mongodb and redis. It similar like twitter

So the scenario is pretty straight forward, once User A follow User B. Later on User's A News feed (Home page) will be shown User B's Activity like what he posted.

Schema for User

```
const UserSchema = new Schema({
  email: { type: String, unique: true, lowercase: true},
});



const followSchema = new Schema(
    {
        user: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, required: true, ref: 'User' },
        target: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, required: true, ref: 'User' },
    });
```

Currently the design of my user's schema is pretty simple, when I follow another user, I will just create the Follow Schema Object

and there is another schema, which is post schema

```
/* This is similar like the Tweet */
var PostSchema = new Schema({
  // Own by the user
  creator: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }
  body: String,
});
```

This schema is for user to post anything, similar like twitter posting.

Let say I have followed bunch of users

```
{
   user: 'me',
   target: 'draco'
},

{
  user: 'me',
  target: 'donald'
},

{
  user: 'me',
  target: 'joker'
}
```

and let say one of my followers, post something. How do i present it to my current news feed?

```
/* I'm following Joker */
app.post('/follow', (req, res, next) => {
   let follow = new Follow();
   follow.user = "me";
   follow.target = "joker";
   // Do i need to use redis to subscribe to him?
   follow.save();
})


/* Joker posted something */
app.post('/tweet',(req, res, next) => {
   let post = new Post();
   post.creator = "joker";
   post.body = "Hello my name is joker"
   post.save();
   // Do i need to publish it using redis so that I will get his activity?

});
```

Here's my attempt

```
app.get('/feed', function(req, res, next) {

     // Where is the redis part?
     User.findOne({ _id: req.user._id }, function(err, foundUser) {
        // this is pretty much my attempt :(
     })
})
```

When should I use redis to actually do the pub and sub? so that I could take the content of one of my followers and show it on my timeline?

Comment: You are not doing anything with your followees instead current user in query

Comment: What should I do to my followees array, should I loop each one of it?

Answer (score 17):

I have built a social network which has a news feed, too. Here is how I did it.

---

Basically, you have 2 methods to built a newsfeed:

1. Fanout on write (push) method
2. Fanout on read (pull) method

---

## Fanout on write

First, you will need another collection:

```
const Newsfeed = new mongoose.model('newsfeed', {
  owner: {type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId, required: true},
  post: {type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId, required: true}
});
```

### When a user post something:

1. Get n follower
2. Push (fanout) this post to n follower

### When a user get a feed:

1. Get from `Newsfeed` collection

### Example:

```
router.post('/tweet', async (req, res, next) => {
  let post = await Post.create({});

  let follows = await Follow.find({target: req.user.id}).exec();

  let newFeeds = follows.map(follow => {
    return {
      user: follow.user,
      post: post.id
    }
  });
  await Newsfeed.insertMany(newFeeds);
});

router.get('/feed', async (req, res, next) => {
  let feeds = await Newsfeed.find({user: req.user.id}).exec();
});
```

---

## Fanout on read

### When a user post something:

1. Save

### When a user get feed

1. Get n following
2. Get posts from n following

### Example

```
router.post('/tweet', async (req, res, next) {
  await Post.save({});
});

router.get('/feeds', async (req, res, next) {
  let follows = await Follow.find({user: req.user.id}.exec();

  let followings = follows.map(follow => follow.target);

  let feeds = await Post.find({user: followings}).exec();
});
```

---

You don't need Redis or pub/sub to implement a newsfeed. However, in order to improve the performance, you may need Redis to implement some kind of cache for this.

For more information or advance technique, you may want to take a look at [this](https://github.com/FreemanZhang/system-design/blob/master/newsFeed.md#pull-based).

Comment: Hey thanks for helping! I'm just wondering where is the redis part thanks!!

Comment: Well, as I said before, you don't really need Redis or pub/sub mechanism to implement the very basic newsfeed. However, you can use Redis to implement caches to improve the performance. Do you want me to shed some light about that?

Comment: @willie17 That would be great if you clarify the Redis part in the above chart.

Comment: @willie17 What are the pros and cons of each methods?

Comment: Link goes to a 404.

Answer (score 7):

User Schema :

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const userSchema = new Schema({
     name:{type:String},
     email: { type: String, unique: true, lowercase: true},
  },{
    collection: 'User'
  });

var User = module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

Follow Schema :

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var followSchema = new Schema(
    {
        follow_id: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, required: true, ref: 'User'  },
        leader_id: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, required: true, ref: 'User' }
    },{
        collection:'Follow'
    });

 var Follow = module.exports = mongoose.model('Follow', followSchema);
```

Post Schema :

```
 var mongoose = require('mongoose');
 var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var postSchema = new Schema({
  creator: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }
  body: {type: String , required:true},
  created_at :{type:Date , default:Date.now}
},{
    collection:'Post'
  });

var Post = module.exports = mongoose.model('Post', postSchema);
```

Now Suppose you have 3 users in User collection :

```
{ _id: ObjectID('5a2ac68d1413751391111111') ,name:'John' , email:'john@gmail.com'}

{ _id: ObjectID('5a2ac68d1413751392222222') ,name:'Morgan' , email:'morgan@yahoo.com'}

{ _id: ObjectID('5a2ac68d1413751393333333') ,name:'Emily' , email:'emily@outlook.com'}
```

> Now John Follows Morgan and Emily :

so in Follow collection there are two records

1)  `follow_id = John's ID` and `leader_id = Morgan's ID`

2)  `follow_id = John's ID` and `leader_id = Emily's ID`

```
{ 
  _id: ObjectID('5a2ac68d141375139999999'),
  follow_id : ObjectID('5a2ac68d1413751391111111'),
  leader_id : ObjectID('5a2ac68d1413751392222222')
},
  {
     _id: ObjectID('5a2ac68d1413751393333333'),
    follow_id : ObjectID('5a2ac68d1413751391111111'),
    leader_id : ObjectID('5a2ac68d1413751393333333')
  }
```

> Now if you want to get User's Following :

```
app.get('/following/:user_id',function(req,res){
      var userid=req.params.user_id;
      Follow.find({follow_id:mongoose.mongo.ObjectID(userid)})
      .populate('leader_id')
      .exec(function(err,followings){
       if(!err && followings){ 
          return res.json({followings:followings});
       }
      });
});
```

> for getting User's Followers :

```
   app.get('/followers/:user_id',function(req,res){
      var userid=req.params.user_id;
      Follow.find({leader_id:mongoose.mongo.ObjectID(userid)})
      .populate('follow_id')
      .exec(function(err,followers){
       if(!err && followers){ 
          return res.json({followers:followers});
       }
      });
});
```

> npm install redis

in your app.js :

```
var redis = require('redis');
var client = redis.createClient();
```

When one user create post :

```
app.post('/create_post',function(req,res){

       var creator=new mongoose.mongo.ObjectID(req.body.creator);
       var postbody=req.body.body;


       async.waterfall([
          function(callback){

          // find followers of post creator

          Follow.find({leader_id:creator})
              .select({ "follow_id": 1,"leader_id":0,"_id": 0})
              .exec(function(err,followers){
                      if(!err && followers){ 
                      callback(null,followers);
                      }
              });
         },
        function(followers, callback){

          // saving the post

         var post=new Post({
            creator: creator,
            body: postbody
         });
          post.save(function(err,post){
             if(!err && post){

   // adding newly created post id to redis by key userid , value is postid

                for(var i=0;i<followers.length;i++){
                   client.sadd([followers[i].follow_id,post.id]);
                }


                 callback(null,post);
             }
         });   
      }
   ], function (err, result) {
             if(!err && result){
                return res.json({status:"success",message:"POST created"});
             }
       });
    });
```

Now For Getting User NewsFeed :

1) first get array of postid from redis key of userid

2) loop through postid and get post from mongo

Function for get newsfeed by userid :

```
app.get('/newsfeed/:user_id',function(req,res){
    var userid=req.params.user_id;
    client.smembers(userid,function(err, reply) {
        if(!err && reply){
            console.log(reply);

            if(reply.length>0){
               var posts=[];

               for(var i=0;i<reply.length;i++){
                  Post.findOne({_id:new mongoose.mongo.ObjectID(reply[i])}).populate('creator').exec(function(err,post){        
                 posts.push(post);
      });
               }

              return res.json({newsfeed:posts});

            }else{
              // No News Available in NewsFeed
            }
        }
    });

});
```

Here we have use redis to store [userid,array of postids] for newsfeed ,
but if you dont want to use redis than just use below Newsfeed Model and store user_id and post_id for newly created post and then display it.

NewsFeed Schema :

```
 var mongoose = require('mongoose');
 var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var newsFeedSchema = new Schema({
  user_id: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, refer:'User' , required:true}
  post_id: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, refer:'Post' , required:true},
},{
    collection:'NewsFeed'
  });

var NewsFeed = module.exports = mongoose.model('NewsFeed', newsFeedSchema);
```

Helpful link for Redis : https://www.sitepoint.com/using-redis-node-js/

for Async : https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#